# How to access provider members within a component in Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a provider having a method getWeather() and I want to call it from home component. When I am trying to call getWeather() from home component I am getting error in console like: ERROR *TypeError: Cannot read property 'getWeather' of undefined*

weather.ts

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import  "rxjs/add/operator/map";

@Injectable()
export class WeatherProvider {

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello WeatherProvider Provider: ');    
  }
   getWeather() {
    return this.http.get('https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=London,us&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22').map(res=>res.json());      
  }

}
```

home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { WeatherProvider } from "../../providers/weather/weather";
//import { HttpModule } from "@angular/http";
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  weather:any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private wp:WeatherProvider) {

  }
  ionViewWillEnter() {

    this.weather.getWeather().subscribe(weather=>{
      console.log(weather)
    })
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is gone after restarting the ionic dev server. I don't know why the ionic is behaving like this.